How to find size or length of char array
I have a char array declared as char input[], and I want to know how to find its size or length. What is the correct syntax or method in C++ to determine the length or size of the char array?
Could you please provide code examples

In C++ don't use plain C-style arrays. Either use std::array or std::vector. Unless you want a string, then use std::string.

Also, once you pass the array to a function, you loose its size information. All you have is a pointer to the first element, which means there's no way to get its length. Unless you have something like a C-style null-terminated string (where you can get the length of the string but not the size of the array).

char input[] is a pointer not an array. There is no way to find the length of an array from a pointer to the array. The simple answer to this mess is to use std::string or std::vector instead. If you provide your code, then I'm sure someone will show you how to rewrite it to use std::string.

You and/or your C++ teacher might find this interesting : Stop teaching "C"

@john char input[] could be an array e.g. here: char input[] = "abc";, but of course I generally agree with everything you wrote.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Problem with plain C-style arrays (e.g. those defined as char input[] = "Some String") is that, when passed to a function (e.g. void someFunc(const char inp[])), the size/length information is lost entirely and the ONLY information passed is the address of a single char.    In C++, learn to use the std::string type (from the standard library, in <string>) since, unlike a C-style array, a std::string object contains information about its size.  In C++17 and later, std::string_view is also useful in SOME situations.

finding size of char array in C++

Where the name of an array is in scope, you can use sizeof to find the size of that array.
char foo[1234];

std::cout << sizeof(foo); // should print 1234

There is, however, a twist to this: when/if you attempt to define a function parameter with a type array of T, the parameter will actually have the type pointer to T. So, if you have something like this:
void printSize(char param[]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(param) << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    char foo[1234];
    char bar[2345];

    printSize(foo);
    printSize(bar);
}

On a reasonably current compiler, this will generally print out 8 for both sizes. On an older compiler, you might get 4 for both. If you get a really old (MS-DOS) compiler, you could even get 2 for both. But always the same size for both, and virtually always 2, 4, or 8.
It's also possible to pass the array to a function template by reference, in which case you can maintain the information about the array's size:
template <std::size_t N>
void printSize(char (&array)[N]) {
    std::cout << N << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    char foo[1234];
    char bar[2345];

    printSize(foo);
    printSize(bar);
}

This should print the sizes as 1234 and 2345. And since printSize is defined to receive an array by reference, if you try to pass something like a pointer instead of an array, the code simply won't compile.
Since it's a template anyway, it's easy to make this work for arrays of different types, not just arrays of char:
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void printSize(T (&array)[N]) {
    std::cout << N << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    char foo[1234];
    long bar[2345];

    printSize(foo);
    printSize(bar);
}

This can produce different results from the first code above though. sizeof yields the number of bytes in an array, but this prints out the number of elements in the array. For any type that isn't one byte, the results will be different (e.g., an array of 1000 shorts will have 1000 elements, but since short is usually two bytes, the sizeof version will show its size as 2000 instead).
Though it's one most would generally advise avoiding, there's one other possibility I suppose I need to mention. You can define a global variable in one file, and a declare it in another. The definition needs to specify the size, but the declaration does not. If the declaration doesn't specify the size, that variable has an incomplete type in the file where it's declared, so even though you can use it in some ways, you can't take its size (in that file). To allow sizeof to work on it, you have to specify its size in the declaration.
extern char foo[]; // legal, but incomplete type
extern char bar[1234]; // legal, complete type


Since C++17,  std::size() has a templated overload that obtains the size of an array that is passed by reference
